# clipping custom shape on canvas android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am trying to provide fill color feature in my android application.In that I want to allow filling color in custom shape as shown in following figure :

[image]

Here, painting should be done in area covered by letter-A and painting outside image boundary should not be allowed.Here I am using Canvas To achieve this functionality.If i use `clipPath()` method of canvas then i can do this efficiently but i want to provide this functionality for all alphabets,then how to achieve this functionality.

Please solve my problem to achieve this functionality.